# Storing SVG paths as javascript variables

Tags: javascript, svg

I seem to be having a bit of an issue storing an SVG path string in a simple javascript variable. This is a bit mystifying to me and I haven't been able to find anything that points to why this might be happening.

The path is stored in a single-line string, with double quotes on each end. That's the only thing in this file, yet when I try to utilize the string with Raphael.js I'm getting that exception error. Thoughts? Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: http://www.screencast.com/t/BR1DHuH2bNm]

Comment: Forgot to mention... I'm using Illustrator to save out my paths and just extracting the SVG path info from the SVG XML.

Comment: Is the SVG data really split across multiple lines like that in your code or is that just the way it appears in the console screenshot?

Comment: Please provide us with your actual code (or better yet, a pared-down test case). A screenshot of the developer tools is not the same thing. Otherwise we can only guess as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not legal in JavaScript to spread a string across multiple lines like it appears to be in your screenshot.  You might edit your code so that the string being assigned to `greenland`  is all on one line or put a backslash to escape the newline character at the end of each line in the string.

Comment: Once again, I prove to myself why I should not be coding at 1am after a full day of work: I didn't have hidden characters turned on in Coda and there were some line breaks in there. I took those out and all is well.